# Count regular status impressions on Facebook

Tags: facebook

How can I count the impressions on a regular post that's posted on a regular Facebook profile (using an app for example)?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that impressions are used for page performance and ads, I don't think you will ever see this metric posted. It's really in the most simplistic form an unnecessary admiration metric in the context of personal profiles.

Probably would be useful for popular users and those with high follower counts. Maybe Facebook can pull such accounts into the ads platform but commercializing personal profiles, in my opinion, doesn't seem like a way to please Facebook users in an already ad-loathing environment.

Using the Graph API, impressions can only be obtained for fan pages not profiles.
The closest metric I can think of is "People who saw this post" available in Facebook groups.